# create-react-app/react-native-elements error

Tags: javascript, react-native-elements

Started a project with create-react-app. Installed react-native: "^0.57.8",react-native-elements: "^0.19.1" and react-native-vector-icons: "^6.1.0". To be able to use components within react-native-elements within a project.

When I run `npm start` I get the error code pasted below. I've read through the the react-native-elements documentation but can't seem to find anything to help me

```
./node_modules/react-native-elements/src/avatar/Avatar.js
 SyntaxError: D:\Location-Map\Neighborhood-Map-2-\location- 
 app\node_modules\react-native-elements\src\avatar\Avatar.js: Unexpected 
 token (92:8)

  90 | 
  91 |       return (
> 92 |         <TouchableHighlight
     |         ^
  93 |           style={[
  94 |             styles.editButton,
  95 |             editButtonSizeStyle,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that (read [here](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/) if you want to know why). Do you want to build a web app? Use React with `create-react-app`. Do you want to build a mobile app? Use React Native with Expo or `react-native init`.

I suggest you look into [`material-ui`](https://material-ui.com/) as a component library for React.

Comment: You can do that with `react-native-web`